# How to define a canonical basis set?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In a N-dimensional space I have K linearly independent vectors (K < N). These vectors define a K dimensional sub-space in the original N dimensional space. We can have other K linearly independent vectors that define exactly the same sub-space.

I would like to find / define a "canonical" set of K linearly independent vectors representing a sub-space. In other words, if I have many different sets of vectors defining the same sub-space, I want to be able to transform them into one "canonical" set of K-vectors.

There is one restriction: all components of all the vectors are positive and the resulting "canonical" set of vectors should have this property as well.

How can one do it?

Comment: It isn't always possible to have all components of the basis vectors positiv, look at the span of $(1,-1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: What you like to find sounds nice, but unfortunably it is not achievable.

Comment: @drhab, why? I am sure it is. I guess our disagreement comes from the understanding of the problem. Let say i have to basis vectors in a 3D space: (0.7, 0.2) and (0.3, 0.9). I am sure that there are two other vectors that define the same plane as the first two vectors.

Comment: When I say unachievable then I am aiming at "canonical".

Comment: @drhab, bit isn't it just a question of definition? Why should it be impossible to define it?

Comment: You could define a base and then say to it: you are canonical! But doing so the term canonical looses its meaning. It should be connected with "natural" or "a choice that speaks for itself" hence hardly requiers any searching or finding.

Comment: As stated the Question scarcely makes sense.  By starting with an (arbitrary) subset of $K$ linearly independent vectors in some $N$-dimensional vector space, we agree that there will be alternative choices for the basis that generates the same subspace as those $K$ vectors span.  But in your penultimate paragraph there is suddenly a mention of "components" which are "positive".  One needs some additional structure to talk about "components" of vectors in a vector space.  Perhaps you have in mind that the original vector space is $\mathbb{R}^N$, but this needs to be explicit.

Comment: @hardmath, yes, I consider vectors whose components are real values.

Comment: @drhab, I do not insist to call it "canonical". The only thing that I need is to have a transformation that replaces a given set of vectors to another set that span the same sub-space. I wont this transformation to give the same set of vectors if we use different sets that represent the same sub-space.